# git mv a bash script to rename a folder of a specific branch inside changes all branches

Tags: git, macos

I'm not quite sure if this is a macOS/zsh specific problem so I'm going to add the tags anyway. Consider [this dummy repository](https://github.com/Foadsf/test_20200324), with some dummy folder and files:

```
test_20200324:master
   |-> test_folder_one
   |     |->....
   |-> test_folder_two
   |     |->....
   |-> test_files...
   |-> setup.sh
```

and a `master` branch. The `setup.sh` is instructed to create a new branch, checkout and rename a folder:

```sh
git branch production
git checkout production 

git mv test_folder_two test_folder_four
```

now after running the script, I expect to see a new branch:

```
test_20200324:production
   |-> test_folder_one
   |     |->....
   |-> test_folder_four
   |     |->....
   |-> test_files...
   |-> setup.sh
```

while the content of the master branch is intact. However, for some reason the script messes the whole repository up (lucky I haven't run that on real production!). The script has renamed that specific folder in all branches. And master branch also has its `test_folder_two` folder renamed to `test_folder_four`. I would appreciate it if you could help me understand what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

Comment: Tag bash **or** zsh, not both. They're distinct, mutually-incompatible shells. (And if you have a zsh script, don't put "bash" in your question title!)

Comment: That said, as for the real question, I'd need to know how you're inspecting or testing the contents of your repository.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well, the issue is that I'm not sure what is the problem. The script I'm using was initially written and tested for bash. So I'm interested to know if other users have a similar issue on bash or this is a macOS/zsh specific problem

Comment: @CharlesDuffy to test the content of a repository I do just `ls`, open in `Finder`, or open the directory in `vscode`. all showing the same weird scenario!

Comment: Okay, I'll tell you right now -- it's not specific to bash *or* zsh. None of the commands you're running are in any way shell specific.

Comment: That said, it looks to me like you simply never *checked in* the `git mv`. It's just part of your working tree state until you commit it on a branch.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't think I can. The words I used above are the most technically correct-for-the-purpose ones I know.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy mind if we do not use chat? I don't like it and the content will not be indexed :(

Comment: Comments are prone to being deleted. Also, importantly, you can paste longer content in chat than you can in comments, and I'm about to ask you for some commands with rather long output.

Comment: Which is to say, comments should *never* be expected to serve as an answer, which it sounds like what you want them to do wrt. being indexed and such. Anything that's actually important / expected to persist should be edited into the question (if a clarification on same) or copied into an answer proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `git mv`, that change is part of your working tree state (and also staged in the sense described in [What does "stage" mean in git?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119782/what-does-stage-mean-in-git)), but *not* yet part of your branch.

This means that if you changed branches, and git *didn't* then try to retain working-tree changes (like that `mv`), then your changes would simply be thrown away.

Throwing away someone's work is bad -- it's not something a source control system should do. Thus, when you switch from one branch to another, git tries to apply uncommitted working tree changes to that new branch (and if they conflict / can't be applied, refuses to complete the checkout).

---

So, how can you stop that from happening?

Just run `git commit -m 'Renamed folder two to four'`, and the change will be firmly put in place on the branch you already have checked out, instead of following your working tree.